# How to Change JQuery Value Through <Input> Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following fiddle converts texts into paragraphs and the problem is the JQuery function attribute `chunkSize = 100;` currently defines the amount of characters for each divided paragraph to contain.

Is it possible for the user to be able to change this dynamically through the use of an `<input>` and `<button>` where the user would be able to type their desired characters for each dynamic paragraph and apply it?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/csz0ggsw/)

If a new fiddle could please be provided, it  would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

Thank You!

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    //Lets target the parent element, instead of P. P will inherit it's font size (css)
    var targets = $('#content'),
      property = this.dataset.property;
    targets.css(property, this.value);
    sameheight('#content p');
  }).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
var btn = document.getElementById('go'),
  textarea = document.getElementById('textarea1'),
  content = document.getElementById('content'),
  chunkSize = 100;
btn.addEventListener('click', initialDistribute);
content.addEventListener('keyup', handleKey);
content.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

function initialDistribute() {
  var text = textarea.value;
  while (content.hasChildNodes()) {
    content.removeChild(content.lastChild);
  }
  rearrange(text);
}

function rearrange(text) {
  var chunks = splitText(text, false);
  chunks.forEach(function(str, idx) {
    para = document.createElement('P');
    para.classList.add("Paragraph_CSS");
    para.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
    para.textContent = str;
    content.appendChild(para);
  });
  sameheight('#content p');
}

function handleKey(e) {
  var para = e.target,
    position,
    key, fragment, overflow, remainingText;
  key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
  if (para.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  if (key != 13 && key != 8) {
    redistributeAuto(para);
    return;
  }
  position = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  if (key == 13) {
    fragment = para.lastChild;
    overflow = fragment.textContent;
    fragment.parentNode.removeChild(fragment);
    remainingText = overflow + removeSiblings(para, false);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
  if (key == 8 && para.previousElementSibling && position == 0) {
    fragment = para.previousElementSibling;
    remainingText = removeSiblings(fragment, true);
    rearrange(remainingText);
  }
}

function handlePaste(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'P') {
    return;
  }
  overflow = e.target.textContent + removeSiblings(fragment, true);
  rearrange(remainingText);
}

function redistributeAuto(para) {
  var text = para.textContent,
    fullText;
  if (text.length > chunkSize) {
    fullText = removeSiblings(para, true);
  }
  rearrange(fullText);
}

function removeSiblings(elem, includeCurrent) {
  var text = '',
    next;
  if (includeCurrent && !elem.previousElementSibling) {
    parent = elem.parentNode;
    text = parent.textContent;
    while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.lastChild);
    }
  } else {
    elem = includeCurrent ? elem.previousElementSibling : elem;
    while (next = elem.nextSibling) {
      text += next.textContent;
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(next);
    }
  }
  return text;
}

function splitText(text, useRegex) {
  var chunks = [],
    i, textSize, boundary = 0;
  if (useRegex) {
    var regex = new RegExp('.{1,' + chunkSize + '}\\b', 'g');
    chunks = text.match(regex) || [];
  } else {
    for (i = 0, textSize = text.length; i < textSize; i = boundary) {
      boundary = i + chunkSize;
      if (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) == ' ') {
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      } else {
        while (boundary <= textSize && text.charAt(boundary) != ' ') {
          boundary++;
        }
        chunks.push(text.substring(i, boundary));
      }
    }
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

```css
#text_land {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

textarea {
  width: 95%;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}

label select {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h3 {
  margin: 1.2em 0;
}

div {
  margin: 1.2em;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  padding: .5em;
}

p {
  /*Here the sliles for OTHER paragraphs*/
}

#content p {
  font-size: inherit;
  /*So it gets the font size set on the #content div*/
  padding: 1.2em .5em;
  margin: 1.4em 0;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h3>Import Text below, then press the button</h3>
  <textarea id="textarea1" placeholder="Type text here, then press the button below." rows="5">
  </textarea>
  <input style="width:200px;" placeholder="Custom Characters per box">
  <button>
    Go
  </button>
  <br>

  <button style="width:200px;" id="go">Divide Text into Paragraphs</button>
</div>
<div>
  <h3 align="right">Divided Text Will Appear Below:</h3>
  <hr>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `sameheight` defined? No `select` element appears at `html` ?

Comment: @guest271314 The sameheight attribute is for a different element. However, is used to change the font size from an option select dropdown.

Comment: `sameheight` appears to be a `function` ? Which is called at `rearrange` function?

Comment: @guest271314 It is to ensure that when the font size is changed, it will apply to all paragraphs.

Comment: If `chunkSize` is set to , for example, `20`, what would be expected result if `50` characters were input into `textarea` ?

Comment: @guest271314  The text would be converted into two separate paragraphs.

Comment: Cannot determine if result is different, though was able to set `chunkSize` using `input type="number"` and `button` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an `id` for your input.

```
<input id="custom" placeholder="Custom Characters per box" style="width:200px;">
```

Add below code into `initialDistribute` function.

```
custom = parseInt(document.getElementById("custom").value); //Get value of the input.

chunkSize = (custom>0)?custom:100; //If Custom value is more than `0`, take that as `chunkSize` value else `100`
```

**[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jenson555/csz0ggsw/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input type="number"` element, `button` element; set `chunkSize` to `input type="number"` `valueAsNumber` property at click of `button`

html

```
  <label>chunkSize:<input class="chunkSize" type="number" /></label> 
  <button class="chunkSize">
  Set chunkSize
  </button>
```

javascript

```
  $("button.chunkSize").click(function(e) {
    var _chunkSize = $("input.chunkSize")[0].valueAsNumber;
    chunkSize = _chunkSize;
  })
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/csz0ggsw/11/